# SocketException on getOutputStream()

Tags: java, tcp, smartystreets

I am trying to get the linked example code to work, but am experiencing a SocketException (below).  I am using java 7.

https://github.com/smartystreets/LiveAddressSamples/blob/master/java/LiveAddressExample.java

```
IO Exception Error: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.icat.coastal.processor.SmartyStreetAddress.main(SmartyStreetAddress.java:71)
```

I think this is due to this line:

```
DataOutputStream outgoing = new DataOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream());
```

I tried adjusting the firewall as suggested here, but it did not work: http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-networking/17319-java-net-socketexception-connection-reset.html

How do I dig deeper to determine the problem, or what do you think could be wrong?

Comment: No need to guess about which line. See the stack trace. Edit it into your question.

Comment: The NPE is due to the json array not being returned which is caused by something wrong with getting the output stream.

Comment: @Jim - The line number in the stack trace (`198`) doesn't correspond with an actual line in the example code (as posted on github). Can you post the exact line that is causing the exception?

Comment: @mdwhatcott It is line 71 in the linked code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried a fresh attempt, copying straight from the github example and inserting my `auth-id` and `auth-token`. Here's what my terminal session looked like:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

$ ll
drwxr-xr-x   6 mike  staff   204B Feb  9 11:49 ./
drwxr-xr-x  18 mike  staff   612B Dec 22 23:01 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 mike  staff   3.2K Feb  9 11:49 LiveAddressExample.java
-rw-r--r--   1 mike  staff   349B Dec 22 23:01 README.md
-rw-r-----@  1 mike  staff    23K Feb  9 11:45 json-simple-1.1.1.jar

$ javac -cp json-simple-1.1.1.jar LiveAddressExample.java 
Note: LiveAddressExample.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: LiveAddressExample.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

$ java -cp .:json-simple-1.1.1.jar LiveAddressExample
3785 Las Vegas Blvd S
Las Vegas NV 89109-4333

1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy
Mountain View CA 94043-1351
```

So at this point I'm having trouble replicating the error. A coworker of mine tried the same thing with java 1.6 and that also worked. Are there any other details you can provide about your environment or any details related to edits you've done to the code?

Comment: Thanks for trying this again.  I'll spin up my app and see what happens.

Comment: I tested this again with the LiveAddressExample class with no modifications.  I am using Java 7.  This worked ok for me this time.  I am using freeform single line addresses.  I tested one of these (which I was testing originally) passing it into the street field and it works as well.  So I must have made a mistake earlier in my code referencing this service.  Thanks again for your help.